# Does Autodesk Viewer meet those requirements?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've been asked to insert an .IFC viewer into a web page already built, to:

- explode building visualization into floors
- rotate the building
- colour spaces based on their temperature
- add labels to objects
- load .ifc files stored on private servers

Does autodesk viewer meet those requirements? All of them?

Additionaly, is it feasible to change the viewer language through a config file or specific functions?

Answer (score 1):

> explode building visualization into floors

The built-in explosion is by model components and not floors and there's option right out of box to specify a granularity level.

Nonetheless you can use `viewer.cutplanes` (see doc [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D.html#setCutPlanes)) to isolate the levels and go from there - see sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/d09ecd51a9dc09606c1fc737d033cf2fab93174d/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.LevelFilter/Viewing.Extension.LevelFilter.js).

> rotate the building

This can be done by either THREE.js transformation or Viewer's model load options:

- THREE.js: Perform transformation recursively by traversing all children components under the model's root dbid. See this great article [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/know-how-complex-component-transformations-viewer-part-1-basics) for enlightenment.
- Load option - see live [sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/g8sp9tvn/):

```
   var options = {       
          placementTransform:THREE.matrix4,  
          globalOffset:{x:0,y:0,z:0}
      };

   viewer.start(svfURL, options）
```

> colour spaces based on their temperature

Use `viewer.setThemingColor` (see doc [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D.html#setThemingColor)) to apply temperature colors - find the parent dbid of the room or and use the recursive flag to apply color to all its children components. See code sample [here](https://github.com/apprentice3d/Niagara-Forge).

> add labels to objects

See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/create-pushpin-markup-svg) for details and a few helpful links at the start of the article.

> load .ifc files stored on private servers

You can download the translated derivatives (SVF and its resources - obtain a manifest of them from [GET :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/)) to your own storage locations and load them by their URL directly. See my live code sample above for details and find the source code for our online extractor tool (http://extract.autodesk.io) [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/master/server/results.js#L169) for ideas to download the derivatives.

> is it feasible to change the viewer language through a config file or specific functions?

Viewer implements [the i18n standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) so you can do:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.i18n.setLng('fr');
Autodesk.Viewing.i18n.localize()
```

Comment: To implement those functions, what APIs are required? Only Data Management and Data Derivative?

Comment: Affirmative - Data Management to upload, store the model and Model Derivative to translate them to SVF for Viewer. Your requirements are all about visualizing with Viewer on the client side so no other services required.